# Cannot Select Recipients in CiviMail in 4.6.2

Tags: civimail, 4.6.2

I'm experiencing the same issues as shown in this thread: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36343.0.html

Fields appear duplicated, I can't select any recipients, etc. In fact, when I select a group (autocomplete search does not work), the field label goes red as if I've missed selecting any recipients.

I've got an urgent mail to get out for this client, but can't do it through CiviMail. I've tried all versions of the layout (standard, unified, unified2 and wizard).

Joomla 2.5.28
CiviCRM 4.6.2
Browsers used: Safari 7, Chrome 42.x, Firefox Developer's Edition

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. It's helpful to report these kinds of issues along with details of the configuration (like you did) and any steps required to reproduce in a new installation.

For a temporary work-around, you might try using the old, deprecated UI by editing `civicrm.settings.php` to include `define('CIVICRM_CIVIMAIL_UI_LEGACY',1);`

FWIW, we still have a couple issues that are getting reported by multiple people but which we cannot reproduce yet. Based on the data-points so far, the use of Joomla with Civi 4.6.2 seems to be a common theme, but that could be coincidence. More reports/debugging is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The new CiviMail UI is written purely in javascript. If your website has plugins/customizations/extensions that crash or otherwise interfere with javascript, it's not going to be pretty.

As a first step troubleshooting, I recommend disabling all plugins, etc. on your website. You can find more tips in the [troubleshooting CiviCRM javascript guide](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).

Comment: Thanks Coleman. I'll get the mail out first using Tim's suggestion above, then I'll look at the plugins and troubleshoot further. I'm seeing some other issues, like clicking the X to close the pop-up doesn't work and if you press Enter in any field, the page assumes you are deleting the draft.

Comment: Great, please report back here what you find.